# Python text file formatting

Tags: python, file, format

I need to do some text file formatting using Python. I have data from serial port, all in one file, one character after another. I know how to find and replace text in the file, but I need to do something like this:

1. Find string int file, (there will be many strings in the file, don't know how many)
2. Set add a space (or another character) after this string. I can't find how to manipulate cursor position in file.

How to get the position of string found in a file?

For example, data in a file is like this:

(this is basically hex data from serial port, but converted to string before saving to file. So in the file this data is just text. There could also be something like "Hello world" inside.

**How to convert this:**

> 00000001030001000151CD0203000100015D1E00000406001000545E5C00000001030001000151CD0203000100015D1E00000406001000545E5C00000001030001000151CD0203000100015D1E00000406001000545E5C00000001030001000151CD0203000100015D1E00000406001000545E5C00000001030001000151CD0203000100015D1E00000406001000545E5C00000001030001000151CD0203000100015D1E00000406001000545E5C00000001030001000151CD0203000100015D1E00000406001000545E5C00000001030001000151CD0203000100015D1E00000406001000545E5C

I would like to find parts starting from "0103" (it is device address), then put "\n" before "0103", then after four following characters put another space and text "this was device number one":

**into this:**

> 000000 0103"this was device number
>   one"0001000151CD0203000100015D1E00000406001000545E5C000000 0103"this
>   was device number
>   one"0001000151CD0203000100015D1E00000406001000545E5C000000 0103"this
>   was device number
>   one"0001000151CD0203000100015D1E00000406001000545E5C000000 0103"this
>   was device number
>   one"0001000151CD0203000100015D1E00000406001000545E5C000000 0103"this
>   was device number
>   one"0001000151CD0203000100015D1E00000406001000545E5C000000 0103"this
>   was device number
>   one"0001000151CD0203000100015D1E00000406001000545E5C000000 0103"this
>   was device number
>   one"0001000151CD0203000100015D1E00000406001000545E5C000000 0103"this
>   was device number one"0001000151CD0203000100015D1E00000406001000545E5C

The whole program is for listening Modbus RTU line, logging purpose.

Comment: I would read everything, do the replace and write it back. Or is your file too large?

Comment: Probably it is a good way. Not sure if my file is to large, it depends on how much transmission I record. Still I don't know how to navigate n characters forward from a string found in my data (that is already read from file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def adjustString(deviceNumber):
    newData = str.replace(data, deviceNumber, '\n' + deviceNumber + ' this was device number one')
    return newData

with open('data.txt', 'r') as myfile:
    data=myfile.read().replace('\n', '')

output = adjustString('0103')
```

You can then write the new string to a file as needed.

```
with open('data.txt') as f:
    f.write(output)
```

Comment: Thank you chumbaloo, it works :)

Is it posible to find a string in a file and then navigate four characters more (leave the four original characters in a file) and put some text after?

Comment: Hi, that is what the str.replace function does. It finds the string match in the example above the deviceNumber, then adds a new line, replaces the 4 characters with the original 4 characters, and then adds text.)

So just change what you want in the str.replace function to get the desired output. 
if you wanted to do more fancy stuff, have a look at the re module in python.

If this was helpful please accept the answer, and happy to have helped :)